# Number timestamps based on time of timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, running-count

I have up to three different timestamps for each day in dataframe. In a new column called 'Category' I want to give them a number from 1 to 3 based on time of the timestamp. Almost like a partition by with rank in sql.

Something like: for each day check the time of run and assign a rank based on if it was the first run, the second or the third (if there is a third run).

This dataframe has about half a million rows. For a few years, 2-3 runs every day. And it has data for on hourly resolution.

Any suggestion how to do this most efficiently?

Example of how it is supposed to look like:

| Timestamp | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-17 08:18:00 | 1 |
| 2020-01-17 11:57:00 | 2 |
| 2020-01-17 15:35:00 | 3 |
|  |  |
| 2020-01-18 09:00:00 | 1 |
| 2020-01-18 12:00:00 | 2 |
| 2020-01-18 17:00:00 | 3 |

Answer (score 1):

```py
df['Category'] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D', key='Timestamp')).cumcount().add(1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
            Timestamp  Category
0 2020-01-17 08:18:00         1
1 2020-01-17 11:57:00         2
2 2020-01-17 15:35:00         3
3 2020-01-18 09:00:00         1
4 2020-01-18 12:00:00         2
5 2020-01-18 17:00:00         3
```

**UPDATE:** Try this:

```
df['Category'] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D', key='Timestamp'))['Timestamp'].diff().ne(pd.Timedelta(0)).cumsum()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use groupby() and .cumcount()

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
df['category'] = df.groupby([df['timestamp'].dt.to_period('d')]).cumcount().add(1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This gives the wrong results unfortunately. This adds a 1 to every row for the same timestamp. Resulting in numbers up to 24 for every hourly data. What it should do is give a 1 to all row with earliest timestamp for a given day (ex: 2020-01-17 08:18:00) , a 2 for the second timestamp og the same day  (ex: 2020-01-17 11:57:00) , and a 3 to the last timestamp of that given day  (ex: 2020-01-17 15:35:00).